# Adding onclick function in anchor tag which is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am have made dropdown using bootstarap. I have added onlcick funtions in my anchor tags in dropdown. I just want make my text box readonly if one of the link is clicked on. I have used js to make text boxes read only. Please Help me to solve my problem. Below is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Mole Calculator | Chemistry Calculator</title>

</head>



<body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h4>
                    <b>Chemistry Calculator</b>
                </h4></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="navbar-nav  text-uppercase">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/about">About</a></li>


                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">

        <div class="card px-4 py-5" style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="card-block">

                <form action="/Chemistry-Calculator/Number-Of-Moles">

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="givenMass" class="form-label">Given Mass of
                            Substance</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="givenMass"
                            aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="givenMass"
                            value="${givenMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="molarMass" class="form-label">Molar Mass</label> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="molarMass" name="molarMass"
                            value="${molarMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="molarMass" class="form-label">Moles</label> <input
                            type="text"  class="form-control"
                            id="molarMass" name="moles" value="${moles}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"
                        value="Calculate">
                        
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Choose what to calculate </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForMoles()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Moles</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForMolarMass()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Molar Mass</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForGivenMass()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Given mass</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My Java Script File:

```
function readonlyForGivenMass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly;
  
}

function readonlyForMolarMass() {
  var x = document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly;
  
}


  
    function readonlyForMoles() {
      var x = document.getElementById("moles").readOnly;
      

}
```

Actually this is small part of java project. Hence I have used jsp and jstl.
My file structure:

[image]

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("moles").readOnly;` **reads** the current state. You are not changing anything here. Second, and more importantly, you are not stopping your links from navigating away from your page. When you navigate, any changes you have made with Javascript in a page are lost in the new page.

Comment: so then how should i do it?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear what exactly you want to happen when someone click those links. Is the navigation supposed to happen, or not?

Comment: No my aim is not navigate anywhere as I want to manipulate my data there itself. My aim is to make one of the input box readonly, if one of those links are clicked

Comment: Still unclear. Is **all** you want to happen when a user clicks *setting another element readonly*? Nothing more? How would this behaviour be useful?

Comment: Also, if you stop the navigation from happening (as you said you want), how does the user get to those pages? Respectively, why do you have `href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator"` on those links at all?

Comment: My aim here is to calculate moles. Just I want to do is make on of the input box as read only. So if the I want calculate the moles, than I need only 2 textbox where I can input . This will make the third one as answer box. So if I want to calculate the molar mass I would need given mass value and moles value. So I want to make the molar mass value read only where my answer will be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just assigning but declaring it, just need to make it true, so given id would be readonly, please find below snippets

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Mole Calculator | Chemistry Calculator</title>

</head>



<body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h4>
                    <b>Chemistry Calculator</b>
                </h4></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="navbar-nav  text-uppercase">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/about">About</a></li>


                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">

        <div class="card px-4 py-5" style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="card-block">

                <form action="/Chemistry-Calculator/Number-Of-Moles">

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="givenMass" class="form-label">Given Mass of
                            Substance</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="givenMass"
                            aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="givenMass"
                            value="${givenMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="molarMass" class="form-label">Molar Mass</label> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="molarMass" name="molarMass"
                            value="${molarMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="moles" class="form-label">Moles</label> <input type="text"  class="form-control"                             id="moles" name="moles" value="${moles}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"
                        value="Calculate">
                        
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Choose what to calculate </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForMoles()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Moles</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForMolarMass()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Molar Mass</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForGivenMass()" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Given mass</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/script.js"></script>
    <script>
function readonlyForGivenMass() {
  document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("moles").readOnly = false;
}

function readonlyForMolarMass() {   
 document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly = false;
     document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("moles").readOnly = false;
}
  

 function readonlyForMoles() {
     document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly = false;
     document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly = false;
    document.getElementById("moles").readOnly = true;
}

    
    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No my friend it is still not working. Actually when I load after clicking on the link, I realized something is happening to that respecting text-box

Comment: Could you plase share the code sandbox, so can help

Comment: I actually don't what is sandbox so i won't be able to share the link

Comment: please check this, and let us know if this is what you are looking for https://jsbin.com/xipemaw/3/edit?html,output

Comment: actually what is happening is that when i click the second link after clicking 1 link the first text box remains read only as true.

Comment: Sharman i have update the code, please check, hope it what you needed https://jsbin.com/xipemaw/16/edit?html,output it working here

Comment: It's working absolutely fine. Please post the answer here so that I will upvote it and mark it as correct

Comment: update the snipped as above, please check, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Mole Calculator | Chemistry Calculator</title>

</head>



<body>

    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h4>
                    <b>Chemistry Calculator</b>
                </h4></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

                <ul class="navbar-nav  text-uppercase">

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                        aria-current="page" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/about">About</a></li>


                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">

        <div class="card px-4 py-5" style="width: 650px;">
            <div class="card-block">

                <form action="/Chemistry-Calculator/Number-Of-Moles">

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="givenMass" class="form-label">Given Mass of
                            Substance</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="givenMass"
                            aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="givenMass"
                            value="${givenMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="molarMass" class="form-label">Molar Mass</label> <input
                            type="text" class="form-control" id="moles" name="molarMass"
                            value="${molarMass}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="molarMass" class="form-label">Moles</label> <input
                            type="text"  class="form-control"
                            id="molarMass" name="moles" value="${moles}" style="width: 600px">
                    </div>

                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit"
                        value="Calculate">
                        
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Choose what to calculate </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item"  onclick="readonlyForMoles(event)" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Moles</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForMolarMass(event)" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Molar Mass</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="readonlyForGivenMass(event)" href="/Chemistry-Calculator/Mole-Calculator">Calculate Given mass</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            function readonlyForGivenMass(event) {
                event.preventDefault()

      var x = document.getElementById("moles").readOnly= false;
  var x = document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly= true;
   var x = document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly= false;
  
}

function readonlyForMolarMass(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
  var x = document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly = true;
  var x = document.getElementById("moles").readOnly= false;
  var x = document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly= false;
  
}


  
    function readonlyForMoles(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
var x = document.getElementById("molarMass").readOnly = false;
      var x = document.getElementById("moles").readOnly = true;
      var x = document.getElementById("givenMass").readOnly= false;
      

}

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you want means you can remove event.preventDefault in each function and
I hope this code will works for you. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your try but the answer is not working

Comment: i Edited the code try once may be it will work .For me it is working